# Returning a QueryDSL BooleanExpression that evaluates to true

Tags: java, null, querydsl

Say I have `CustomerQueryInfo` bean with the following properties:

- String firstName
- String lastName
- StatusEnum status

I want to perform a "**QueryDSL**" search using this an object of this type that will return a list of customers `List<Customer>`.

If one of the fields of `CustomerQueryInfo` is `null`, I don't want to use it in the search. Thus a `CustomerQueryInfo` object with all three **fields set to `null`** will return **all customers**.

I am looking for best practices to perform such a search with QueryDSL.

Is something like this OK:

```
private BooleanExpression isFirstNameLike(String firstName){
    if(firstName==null)
        return true BooleanExpression somehow;
    return QCustomer.customer.firstName.like(firstName);
}

private BooleanExpression isStatutEq(StatusEnum status){
    if(status==null)
        return true BooleanExpression somehow;
    return QCustomer.customer.status.eq(status);
}
```

then:

```
return query.from(customer).where(isFirstNameLike(customerQueryInfo.getFirstName).and(isLastNameLike(customerQueryInfo.getLastName).and(isStatusEq(customerQueryInfo.getStatus))).list;
```

1. How do I return a `BooleanExpression` that evaluates to true?
2. If the above approach is not advisable, then what is the recommended best practice?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can safely use null predicates like this

```
private BooleanExpression isFirstNameLike(String firstName){
    return firstName != null ? customer.firstName.like(firstName) : null;        
}

private BooleanExpression isStatusEq(StatusEnum status){
    return status != null ? customer.status.eq(status) : null;
}
```

And use the varargs aspect of where

```
query.from(customer)
     .where(
         isFirstNameLike(customerQueryInfo.getFirstName()),
         isLastNameLike(customerQueryInfo.getLastName()),
         isStatusEq(customerQueryInfo.getStatus()))
     .list(customer);
```

Comment: Not sure if related, but today I ran into a problem in QueryDSL 3.5.0 (with spring-data-jpa) where `isTrue()` returned everything correctly, but `eq(Boolean.TRUE)` returned nothing. However, `eq(Boolean.FALSE)` worked correctly. Is this a bug?

Comment: Skipping nulls in where is documented. Is it possible to do the same for `BooleanExpression.and(Predicate)`? Currently null skipping is an implementation detail here and null behaviour is not documented while the parameter is annotated as @Nullable.

Answer (score 44):

> How do I return a BooleanExpression that evaluates to true?

```
BooleanExpression alwaysTrue = Expressions.asBoolean(true).isTrue();
```

Comment: Seemed like a great solution, but in my case I ended up with `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Illegal operation true = true
 at com.querydsl.mongodb.MongodbSerializer.visit(MongodbSerializer.java:259`

Comment: Works here with Oracle. Seems to be an issue related to the combination with MongoDB.

Comment: When you find a working solution for MongoDB then please let us know. Maybe something that is converted to `1=1` works?! We just need anything tautological ...

Comment: Actually, the `BooleanBuilder` (see Lam Le's answer) ended up working perfectly.  I did not realize at first that the `BooleanBuilder` is a `Predicate` so you can pass it directly to the `where` clause once you're done building it.

Comment: If you're already there, why not use `Expressions.TRUE`?

Comment: @OrangeDog Expressions.TRUE does not work solely as Predicate in where-clause.

Comment: @FabianBarney `Expressions.TRUE.isTrue()` does though

Comment: @OrangeDog Does it have any advantages over the other statement except that it is more readable? Nevertheless I would like to adjust my answer to your statement if it's ok for you?

Comment: @FabianBarney it'll be slightly faster, skipping ~6 method calls.

Answer (score 8):

With java 8 and BooleanBuilder you can achieve elegant way like this:

Java 8 Optional & Lambda

```
public final class ProductQuery {
    public static BooleanExpression nameEqualTo(String name){
        return ofNullable(name).map(QProduct.product.name::eq).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

BooleanBuilder

```
BooleanBuilder where = new BooleanBuilder()
    .and(ProductQuery.nameEqualTo(name));
```

Answer (score 6):

I create a QueryDSLHelper class which has static methods which do the null check before adding the expression. Something like this:

```
public static void goe(BooleanBuilder builder, DateTimePath<Date> path, Date value) {
    if(date!=null) {
        builder.and(path.goe(value));
    }
}

public static void like(BooleanBuilder builder, StringPath path, String value) {
    if(value!=null) {
        builder.and(path.like(value));
    }
}
```

Now I can just statically import those methods and call them on one line:

```
        like(builder, book.isbn, isbn);
```

This is extremely useful and very clean/readable when implementing 'filter' or 'filterByExample' queries.

Although, the answer above from Timo is probably better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
private BooleanExpression isFirstNameLike(String firstName){
    final QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;
    return customer.firstName.isNull().or(customer.firstName.like(firstName));
}

private BooleanExpression isStatutEq(StatusEnum status){
    final QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;
    return customer.status.isNull().or(customer.status.eq(status));    
}
```

Or if you want to really match `firstName` and/or status then change
the

```
.isNull().or(...) to isNotNull().and(...)
```